# Does pygame.colliderect() work the same way in both of these situations?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Say I have 2 hitboxes: hbox1 and hbox2. Does

```py
hbox1.colliderect(hbox2)
```

and

```py
hbox2.colliderect(hbox1)
```

always return the same thing?

Comment: @Rabbid76, Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `colliderect` evaluates, if a `pygame.Rect` object intersects, with a rectangle. `hbox1` and `hbox2` are rectangle objects, then the result of `hbox1.colliderect(hbox2)` is equal to the result of `hbox2.colliderect(hbox1)`. The operation is [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).
But note, that the argument to `colliderect` does not need to be a `pygame.Rect` object. The argument is allowed to be a tuple, with 4 components (x, y, width, height), too.

If the rectangles (`x1`, `y1`, `w1`, `h1`) and (`x2`, `y2`, `w2`, `h2`) are intersection can be evaluated by:

```py
intersect = x1 < x2+w2 and x2 < x1+w1 and y1 < y2+h2 and y2 < y1+h1
```

It is easy to see that the two rectangles can be swapped and the result will be the same.